# NServiceBus 4.03 Performance Counters in production

Tags: performancecounter, production, nservicebus4

I am enabling performance counters using profiles in our development environment. I am thinking of using it in production.

Would it impact the performance if we enable these counters in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be insignificant compared to any work you'd do in your system.